# matrices: proof for properties of negative exponents

Tags: matrices, inverse

I came across this proof on p.86 of Elementary Linear Algebra by Howard Anton regarding the subject line.

$kA$ is invertible for any non-zero scalar $k$ and $(kA)^{-1} = k^{-1}A^{-1}$.

$(kA)(k^{-1}A^{-1})=k^{-1}(kA)A^{-1}=(k^{-1}k)AA^{-1}=(1)I =I$
similarly $(k^{-1}A^{-1})=(kA)=I$.  Thus $kA$ is invertible and $(kA^{-1}) = k^{-1}A^{-1}$.

I am confused of the part right after "similarly".  Shouldn't $(k^{-1}A^{-1}) = (kA)^{-1}$?  That is what it says at the end of the first line.

Comment: There is probably a typo; it should read $(k^{-1} A^{-1})(kA) = I$, which is proved in the same way that $(kA)(k^{-1} A^{-1})=I$ is proved in the line just before it.

Comment: @angryavian no typo.  I double checked.  Here it is on screencast.  https://www.screencast.com/t/Yz2Zwc04

Comment: @angryavian.  Skyking concurs that it was probably a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you certainly do **not** have $k^{-1}A^{-1} = kA$, take for example $A=I$ which would mean that basically $k^{-1}=k$ for any non-zero $k$.

The parenthesis around $kA$ doesn't make sense unless you actually invert it. Unfortunately there's a parenthesis around $k^{-1}A^{-1}$ which doesn't make sense either.

What it probably should read is that $(k^{-1})A^{-1})(kA) = I$ that way the parenthesis make some sense (although multiplication is associative). Also it is similar to the first equality.

Note that it would be erroneous to write $(kA)^{-1}$ before you actually established that it is invertible, that is, $k^{-1}A^{-1}$ is the inverse (which is done with the two parts of the proof).

Comment: I just posted on screencast and fairly certain I posted it accurately as in the textbook.  Could it be a typo in the book?

Comment: @NickAnoyot Yes, it's most probably a typo and I argue that the probable fault is that there is an equal sign where there should have be none. Note that I don't mean that it's your fault - even respected authors of books does these kind of errors...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.